# Multiple awk pattern matching in one line

Tags: awk

Let's say I want to match `foo` and `bar` in a file. The following works :

`/foo/{commands}/bar/{commands}`
 Note: here there is no separator between `/foo/{commands}` and `/bar/{commands}`.

The following is also okey:

`/foo/{commands1}{commands2}` where `{commands2}` is executed for every line and I've left out the pattern.

But what if I want to leave out the commands? What's awk's syntax rule here? The following doesn't work:

`/foo//bar/`

Of course, I could write it as `/foo/{print}/bar/{print}`, but I was wondering what's the delimiter for separating segments and why you sometimes need it and sometimes you don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`awk` works on method of `regexp` then `action` in this if we are mentioning `/..../` and not mentioning any action so when condition is TRUE then by default print of line will happen. In case you want to put this into 2 different statements try like:

```
awk '/foo/;/bar/'  Input_file
```

Above will mean like:

1. Since they are segregated with `;` these will be treated as 2 different conditions.
2. When `/foo/` is true for any line then NO action is mentioned so print of that line will happen.
3. When `/bar/` is true for any line same thing for this also, condition is true and no action mentioned so print of line will happen.

But point to be noted that in case any line has both strings in it so that line will be printed 2 times, which I believe you may NOT want it so you could do like following:

OR within single condition itself try something like:

```
awk '/foo|bar/'  Input_file
```

Or in case you need to check if strings present in same line then try Like:

```
awk '/foo/ && /bar/'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks. One quick question: Why don't we need '```;```' in ```/foo/{print}/bar/```? This does the same thing, only I've included the {print} explicitly.

Comment: @secluded, Because `/foo/` is a condition if  that is true then you are printing `{print}` that line so it completes the cycle as I mentioned in my answer too then again you are mentioning 1 condition/regexp which need not to be segregated with a `;`. Lemme know in case of any more queries please?

Comment: So you mean in something like ```/foo//bar/```, although the default action is ```{print}``` for ```/foo/```, the cycle is not completed and that's why you need ```;```. Is that right?

Comment: @secluded, no but it is not  the proper way to do it, `condition` then `action` in this case both are conditions, so in case you want to use both conditions on a single line then use either `/foo/||/bar/` for or conditions to check strings OR `/foo/&&/bar/` AND condition to check both strings on a single line. I hope it helps you now.

Comment: Aha! Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*To match `foo` and `bar` in a file* - just combine patterns:

```
awk '/foo/ && /bar/ ....'
```